# How to create a static instance of a page at application startup time?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, navigation, instance

I currently have a MainWindow that acts as a frame to navigate to other pages in my solution. The problem is, i require one of my pages to be instantiated for the entire duration of my application instead of every time when i navigate to a page, that page gets re-instantiated. I have tried the `KeepAlive='true'` property for my page but it did not work.

I would like to know if theres a way to implement "this static instance of a page" method for my codes. Thanks. (p.s im not looking or planning to implement the MVVM approach)

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Instanciate ApiStartup class and Initialize the HTTPClient
            ApiStartup.InitializeClient();
            Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
            Loaded += OnMainWindowLoaded;
        }

        private void OnMainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeView(new DetectionPage());
        }

        public void ChangeView(Page view)
        {  
            MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(view);
        }  

        private void quiz_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            mainWindow?.ChangeView(new DetectionPage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use static value for use in entire application from start to end then you can mention it in app.config file. And easily you can use like `((App)Application.current).KeepAlive` in your any xaml file.

Comment: Do i use ```((App)Application.current).KeepAlive``` in the app.config file?

Comment: No you should assign variable there only and then you can use that variable globally in application.

Comment: @Harry When you try that line of code in a scratch app yourself. What happens?

Comment: it will give you static value which you have mentioned there in app.config file.

Answer (score 0):

A page has the keepalive property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.page.keepalive?view=netframework-4.8

You may set that to true on whichever page you like.
When  you later use navigation methods to navigate to that url, the first instance of the page will be returned.

If that doesn't suit for whatever reason you could cache instances of pages using a dictionary with key type and value page (instance). Then implement some logic decides which pages you do or do not cache in there.

You said you don't want to use mvvm but I think it best to at least mention what almost everyone else does. For other people who intend working in a team then MVVM will be expected and hence for other people reading:

Since pages and frames come with a journal and memory overheads that are often undesirable, most teams (I have encountered) use usercontrols rather than pages. These are presented via a contentcontrol. You can set content to a usercontrol but most teams use viewmodel first. State that matters is bound and templated from an instance of a viewmodel. To retain state between "navigations" a reference to the viewmodel is retained - which is almost guaranteed to be way lighter on memory than any sort of view.

Comment: Thanks, i shall try out the ```KeepAlive``` property approach again in my page, if that doesn't work, maybe i'll try switching in usercontrols instead of pages. Basically are u trying to say that usercontrols allow for lesser consumption of memory and resources and also provides a way to navigate between views without losing the instance?

Comment: It's the combination of frame and page which has memory overheads. View state is retained, instances of pages are retained etc. A viewmodel is just a plain class so you bind the properties you're interested in and your memory use is just those plus the pointers involved in a class instance. A view, on the other hand, has controls and control states. Hence there is a lower memory overhead if you template viewmodels into views. A BIG reason for going MVVM, though, is that this is what everyone does. You ask a question people will say MVVM. You go to an interview, they will ask you about mvvm.